# What causes the "Flash busy" message (Canon EOS 1100D)?

Tags: canon, flash, popup-flash, power-supply

Yesterday I was faced with a situation where I often saw the message "flash busy" with no chance to shoot. As I understand it, this can happen when battery power to flash is low, but I only used the built-in flash (default kit flash). Please explain when and why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "flash busy" message is shown when the flash is charging and not yet ready to be used.

The flash works by slowly charging a capacitor from the batteries and then discharging all that power in a very short time.

If your batteries are low on power or you have low quality batteries it will take longer to charge the flash and so you'll see a lot of "flash busy", also, if it's dark and you need to use the flash on high power it will take longer to charge.

Comment: Nir thank you! Does flash from kit has it's own capacitor?

Comment: @Edward83 - every flash, the flash needs to generate a lot of light in a very short time, a lot of light requires a lot of power, a battery can't provide lots of power in a short time - so you need to get the power out of the battery slowly and store it in something where you can get it out into the "lamp" quickly