# Is it safe to override my camera's "flash busy" warning when the battery is low?

Tags: flash, popup-flash

When I get the "flash busy" message, I usually restart my camera, or just push the flash back, and it pops up again. Both worked for me. Am I damaging my camera or flash this way?
Or it will just result in lower light from Flash?

I am using the on-camera popup flash.

Comment: See also
[“Flash busy” message - When does it happen and why?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40919/flash-busy-canon-eos-1100d-message-when-does-it-happen-and-why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flash typically wont fire if it is not charged enough to fire, so I don't believe there is any risk of damage.

I would recommend that you simply change the battery rather than trying to work around the laws of physics.

Comment: @derinxy Frankly speaking I did knew the reason behind this. Once I came to know I was curious if I was doing something wrong. 
Secondly I wanted to be sure what can happen if in case I have to do it again(for whatever reason, like out of battery, etc).

Comment: @RajatSaini I would use it as a last resort. It shouldn't do any damage though. The flash works by charging a capacitor and then discharging that stored energy. As the battery get flat its voltage drops which means it takes longer and longer to charge that capacitor. If you discharge the capacitor prior to it being 'full' you will just get a weaker pulse of energy from it which will just lead to a lower light output from the flash. That's just based on my relatively limited knowledge of electronic engineering.